# How can I use two arrays to check if DNS records exists in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, function, variables, dns

I want to check if the following records exist with two arrays. I'm not sure if this is the best way of going about it, but from the logic it looks like it may be possible from the code below:

```
Domain_checking () {
    array=(
        grafana
        kibana
        prometheus
        alertmanager
    )

    array2=(
        Name
        NXDOMIAN
    )


    for index in ${!array[*]}; do 
        echo "checking that ${array[$index]} exists in the domain domain.co.uk"
        DOMAIN_CHECK=$(nslookup ${array[$index]}.domain.co.uk | grep {array2[$index]})
        if [[ $DOMAIN_CHECK == *'Name'* ]]; then
            echo "The A record for ${array[$index]}.domain.co.uk exists"
        elif [[ $DOMAIN_CHECK == *'NXDOMIAN'* ]]; then 
            echo "The A record for ${array[$index]}.domain.co.uk dose not exist"
        fi
    done
}

Domain_checking
```

When the code above is run, the loop does start and for the `echo` statement, I see the values in both arrays when I add `{array2[$index]}` to the `echo` statement.

But the array values are not present in `DOMAIN_CHECK`, which I'm not sure as to why this is as the for loop does iterate.

So I would expect that `DOMAIN_CHECK` should have some sort of value and hit the if statement but for some reason, this doesn't seem to be the case. Why is that?

Comment: Can you replace all instances of "the variable" with which variable you're referring to?

Comment: ok I have updated the question the variable is DOMAIN_CHECK

Comment: What do you expect to achieve with `| grep {array2[$index]}`? Either way, you have a syntax error, should be `| grep ${array2[$index]}`

Comment: sorry I didn't see that syntax error, my bad eyes thank you for pointing that out,  yes DOMAIN_CHECK now has data init but I only seem to get grafana instead of seeing everything  being kibana, prometheus and alertmanager just getting 
    Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...    Try 'grep --help' for more information. I think that's because of the NXDOMAIN in the second array not quite sure on a way around this just yet

Comment: Learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . When you use shellcheck, you need to include a proper "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` . AND avoid the top 10 shell script beginner mistakes by reading https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info multiple times. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're only using `nslookup` to see if the domain exists or not, rather than looking for specific information from the command. You can simplify by just checking the exit code instead of using grep:

```
Domain_checking () {
    array=(
        grafana
        kibana
        prometheus
        alertmanager
    )

    for domain in ${array[@]}
    do
      if nslookup "${domain}.domain.co.uk" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        echo "$domain exists"
      else
        echo "$domain does not exist"
      fi
    done
}

Domain_checking
```

If the domain record exists, `nslookup` will return `0` and the `if` condition will be satisfied. Anything else indicates a failure and the control will fall through to the `else`.

Answer (score 2):

You use `$index` as an index to both arrays, but there's a matching entry in `$array2` only for the first entry.  That's why the other entries aren't showing up, and also why grep is missing it's required argument.

Thinking through your logic, I don't see any reason not to remove the second array completely and hard code in `Name` for the grep.

Come think of it, the first array isn't helping much either.  You could simplify the code by iterating across the names themselves rather than their array indices.

```
domain=some.thing
names="kibana prometheus graphite"
for name in $names; do
   nslookup $name.$domain ....
done
```

Comment: Hi thank you for helping me out, You are correct in terms of simplifying the code, I think because the 2nd array finishes earlier then the 1st I would have to loop the 2nd array which is less than ideal in order for it to work properly